# Eway recurring issue with activemerchant gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant, recurring, eway

I am trying to setup `EWay payment integration` with `Active-merchant Gem` in `Rails` application.

I setup successfully EWay but when tried to `Recurring` at that time got issue below:

```
undefined method `recurring' for #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::EwayGateway:0x000000051bb110>.
```

I tried a lot but still not found any proper solution.

Anyone have a better solution or experience with EWay recurring then please provide that will a lot of help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The eWAY gateway module in Active Merchant doesn't have a `recurring` function at this time, which is causing the error you see. In fact, it seems recurring functionality is being removed from the library on the whole:

> There is too much variance between the recurring functionality
>   provided by gateways for ActiveMerchant to do a good job of
>   abstracting it. Thus this deprecates all such functionality with the
>   intention of stripping it out completely at some future point.

[Commit message 8 May 2014](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/commit/0019b4e505d2f2c31c8cc8e2161881a179856789)

If you do want to implement recurring payments with eWAY, your options are:

- Use Tokens to store cards with eWAY (which Active Merchant supports) and manage the recurring billing in your application.
- Skip using Active Merchant and implement eWAY's [Recurring API](https://eway.io/api-v3/?ruby#recurring-payments) directly